# Mapping GraphQL query to Select() linq to sql

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq-to-sql, graphql, azure-cosmosdb

I am building an Web API with .NET core using `GraphQL` and `DocumentDb`.

In theory, `GraphQL` is optimized the data is shipped across the network and thus avoid over-fetching data. But I recognize that the backend server and database is doing the extra unnecessary work (query the entire document) when querying the database.

The best strategy here is using `Select()` to specific properties we need to fetch. But I have no idea how to build the expression from client's query that so complex.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: invisible queries are simple, they returns null or errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For translating linq-expressions to graphql-query you can use library:**
https://github.com/RDavydenko/SmartGraphQLClient

1. Install Nuget-package:

```cs
Install-Package SmartGraphQLClient
```

2. Add services to DI:

```cs
services.AddSmartGraphQLClient();
```

3. Use linq-syntax:

```cs
using SmartGraphQLClient;

GraphQLHttpClient client = ... // from DI

var users = await client.Query<UserModel>("users")
    .Include(x => x.Roles)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Users)
    .Where(x => x.UserName.StartsWith("A") || x.Roles.Any(r => r.Code == RoleCode.ADMINISTRATOR))
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Id,
        Name = x.UserName,
        x.Roles,
        IsAdministrator = x.Roles.Any(r => r.Code == RoleCode.ADMINISTRATOR)
    })
    .Skip(5)
    .Take(10)
    .Argument("secretKey", "1234")
    .ToListAsync();
```

Your request will be translated to graphql-query:

```
{ 
    users (
      where: {
        or: [ 
          { userName: { startsWith: "A" } }
          { roles: { some: { code: { eq: ADMINISTRATOR } } } }
        ]
      }
      skip: 5
      take: 10
      secretKey: "1234"
  ) {
        id
        userName
        roles {
            code
            name
            description
            id
            users {
                userName
                age
                id
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For a SQL expression if we want to query for jedis and we want the columns name and side, we can use the script as below:

```
SELECT name, side
FROM jedis;
```

Let's update the code with our query like so:

```
var json = schema.Execute(_ =>
{
    _.Query = "{ jedis { name, side } }";
});

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

and the result is:
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://dev.to/dotnet/learn-how-you-can-use-graphql-in-net-core-and-c-4h96) and this [one](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.GraphQL/issues/61).

Comment: Thank you for reply, but seem like it's not solve for the question I am asking

Comment: As the [link](https://www.nrecosite.com/graphql_to_sql_database.aspx#faq2) you provided, Graphql-to-SQL engine uses open-source `NReco.Data`. This library can be used with existing ADO.NET providers like azure sql which is contains cosmosdb.

Answer (score 2):

> But I have no idea how to build the expression from client's query that so complex.

What kind of complex query do you have? Just need to fetch only fields those are existed in grapql query? Well, at least one component that already tested in production I know.
If you need solution from the box (looks like you have already had GraphQL.Net, so, it's under .net stack lib), might be sth like [NReco.GraphQL](https://itnext.io/graphql-api-for-sql-database-in-net-af2fe322fe28) could help you to resolve an issue (just need  to set up graphql schema definitions in json-file and connection string to db) which is translating graphql query (even related, even with aggregate functions) to sql query with exactly the same fields as you have in graphql query.

Comment: Thanks for your recommend, but I am using cosmos db, and seems like it haven't yet support :)

Comment: ref: https://www.nrecosite.com/graphql_to_sql_database.aspx#faq2

Comment: as far as I know, add adapter to connect to cosmo db it's not big deal. anyway, I's recommend to ping support if it's still actual